# C Matrix function design for chainging and freeing

Tags: c, matrix, memory-leaks, chaining

So currently I am using a little matrix library that I wrote for a project, but what I hate is how I need to use temporary variables to store pointers to matrices to avoid memory leaks

Example:

```
matrix_t* matrix_add(matrix_t* m1, matrix_t* m2)
{
    assert(m1 != NULL && m2 != NULL);
    assert(m1->rows > 0 && m2->rows > 0 && m1->cols > 0 && m2->cols > 0);
    assert(m1->rows == m2->rows && m1->cols == m2->cols);

    matrix_t* sum = matrix_constructor(m1->rows, m1->cols);

    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<m1->rows; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<m1->cols; j++)
        {
            matrix_set(sum, i, j, matrix_get(m1, i, j) + matrix_get(m2, i, j));
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

so as you can see if I wanted to chain operations together like 2 matrix adds (A + B + C) then I would have to do something like:

```
matrix_t* temp = matrix_add(A, B);
matrix_t* sum = matrix_add(temp, C);
free_matrix(temp);
```

This also gets wayyy uglier when there is a long chain of operations since a temporary variable is needed for each one. My question is does anyone have any design strategies that would make my life easier and code cleaner by being able to chain operations and avoid memory leaks.

I was thinking I could send a variable length argument with variable length operations but that could get messy when many different operations are introduced like matrix transposes and operations that require different sized matrices.

Comment: Define a third parameter for `matrix_add` for the result of the add? So that you can ping pong between just two `matrix_t` variables. `matrix_t r1, r2; matrix_add(A, B, &r1); matrix_add(&r1, C, &r2); matrix_add(&r2, D, &r1); matrix_add(&r1, E ,&r2);` etc.

Comment: That solution dosn't fix the problem though. I still have to free the matrices outside of the function and there are cases where I will need more than 2 temporary variables. matrix addition is not the only case where chaining is needed.

Comment: Personally I think calling a function to get or set a matrix element is a bit excessive.  If you're willing to pay that high a cost, then I would suggest using a non-compiled language like Python.  The only reason to do it in C is for speed, and you're throwing away that advantage.

Comment: Problem is I am writing it for a class and I am going to be parallelizing it later on, so the point of the assignment is learning. Also the code will be parallelized in OpenMP, OpenMPI, and Cuda which are all spin offs of C. You are right that using a getter and setter is excessive but I could turn them into macros in the future I just do not feel like dealing with that right now.

Comment: How about pass in an array of matrix_t and have the function do the entire chain in one go?

Comment: I see - that makes sense.  I have a few thoughts about your problem that I'm still mulling over.

Comment: If your matrix structures were fixed-length, then you could just pass and return them by value and the compiler would take care of the memory allocation and freeing for you.  But since they aren't, I don't think this approach will work.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to implement a memory pool supervisor. When memory is allocated, the supervisor stores the pointer in a list. When it's time to clean up, the supervisor frees all the memory in its list.

The top-level code would look something like this

```
mempool_t *pool = pool_create();
matrix_t *temp, *sum;
temp = matrix_add(pool, A, B);
temp = matrix_add(pool, temp, C);
temp = matrix_add(pool, temp, D);
sum  = matrix_add(pool, temp, E);
pool_destroy(pool, sum);
// ...
// use sum for something
// ... 
free(sum);
```

The `pool_create` function creates a data structure to keep track of all of the memory allocations. This could be a linked list, or a resizable array.

The `matrix_add` function passes the `pool` to the constructor

```
matrix_t *sum = matrix_constructor(pool, m1->rows, m1->cols);
```

The `matrix_constructor` adds the allocated memory to the pool

```
matrix_t *ptr = malloc(...);
pool_add(pool, ptr);
```

The `pool_destroy` function calls `free` on every pointer in the list, except for the pointer that's passed as the second argument. So in the example, `sum` is not freed, and must be freed later by the top-level code.

Comment: I like this idea as a potential way to clean up the code ... It would also allow me to chain them together like matrix_add(pool, matrix_add(pool, A, B), C);

Comment: @BrianCrafton Oh yeah that's true, didn't think about that, but that should work.